# Eclipse criando getter com o prefixo is

Tags: java, eclipse, getters-setters, getters

Eu criei os métodos através do comando Getters and Setters do Eclipse, porém ao criar o getter do atributo booleano `status`, o mesmo foi criado automaticamente como `isStatus`. Não deveria ser criado como `getStatus`?

Alguém poderia me ajudar ou explicar o motivo?

Comment: Complementando minha dúvida, a variável declarada é: private boolean status;

Comment: Talvez porque um atributo booleano geralmente é definido para caracterizar o objeto como é/não é algo. Neste caso, definiria como "estado verdadeiro" ou "estado falso", o que não parece fazer muito sentido. Mude o nome para "ativo" e verá que faz total sentido existir o método `isActive`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atributos booleanos, lógicos, têm uma semântica aprimorada no getter ao serem gerados automaticamente pela IDE.

Talvez com um atributo de nome `status` não seja o melhor caso. Pense no *getter* da propriedade `administrador`.

```
private boolean administrador;
public boolean isAdministrador() { ... }
```

É semanticamente melhor os *getters* de objetos lógicos terem o prefixo `is` em casos particulares.

Tenha em mente também que o padrão `getPropriedade` e `setPropriedade` não é uma regra.

Isso não vale só para os *getters*. Imagine uma classe `Pessoa` com um atributo `estadoCivil`. Vê a vantagem semântica do *setter* de `estadoCivil` ser `casar()` ou `divorciar()`?

De qualquer forma é possível desativar essa configuração do Eclipse em `Settings > Code Style > Java > Use 'is' prefix for getters that return boolean.`

Answer (score 4):

A especificação **JavaBeans** determina padrões a serem seguidos na escrita de objetos Java.

Na versão [**1.0.1**](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) da especificação, mais precisamente na seção **8.3.2** são especificadas as boas práticas para *propriedades booleanas*:

> 8.3.2 Boolean properties
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> ```
> public boolean is<PropertyName>();
> ```
>
> This “is” method may be provided instead of a “get” method, or it may be provided in
>   addition to a “get” method. In either case, if the
>   “is” method is present for a boolean property then we
>   will use the “is” method to read the property value. An
>   example boolean property might be:
>
> ```
> public boolean isMarsupial();  
> public void setMarsupial(boolean m);
> ```

Como a propriedade é *booleana*, então o **is** melhora a leitura do *getter*.

Exemplificando:

1. Uma classe *X* possui um atributo **enabled** do tipo *boolean*
2. **true** está para sim, assim como **false** está para não
3. O **is** em inglês é equivalente a "**é/está**" em português

   1. **isEnabled** pode ser traduzido para o português como: "**está ativado?**"

Logo, podemos concluir que a sua IDE está criando os *getters* dos *booleans* com o prefixo **is** ao invés do **get** pois está seguindo a **Especificação JavaBeans**